# The requested URL [filename].php was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, netbeans, localhost

I tried to run a Netbeans PHP project as a local website (running on local server), however, when I run it, there is a 404 not found error. The error message is:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

And when I tried to visit `localhost/test.php`, the same error appears. I have turned on Apache and MySQL by using `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` and `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` commands. And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO2yB.jpg) is the PHP setting in my Netbeans. Do I need to connect the project to the server or do some other configuration?

Comment: Post your  code in `.htaccess` file too and which folder have you kept the files?

Comment: @sa-7 I cannot locate it. Is it supposed to be under the project folder?

Comment: `.htaccess` under the project folder

Comment: @sa-7 no I do not see it. I used ls -a command and still can't find it